# What population size is reasonable for a moving, steam powered, predatory city?

Tags: population, steampunk, cities, nomads

For a DnD campaign, I'm designing a setting with steampunkish tech level, as well as magic used to explain tech accomplishments not possible with real world physics. Almost all settlements in this world are "moving cities", powered by extensive clockwork mechanisms, that gain the majority of their resources through either moving to a new area and harvesting the wood/coal/etc that can be naturally found there, or through stealing resources from other, smaller, cities.

My question for you all is: **What sort of population numbers would be reasonable for the Large and Medium cities of the world?**

For context, the world will contain the following city sizes:

- Large city - primarily fully predatory, taking resources from medium
  sized and small cities. Constantly in motion.
- Medium cities - some economies and resource acquisition from trade
  with other cities or harvest of the surrounding areas, but also
  predication on smaller cities.
- Small city - primarily gain resources through harvesting from the
  natural resources around them. These are probably going to be no more
  than 100 people.
- Sedentary settlement - extremely small, less than 10 people.
  Primarily hiding from the cities to avoid being preyed on, but rarely
  trading with some of the cities.

I'm attempting to set this up roughly like a food ecosystem web, except with cities rather than animals. Additionally, leaders of large cities have an agreement to attempt to preserve this system, so "harvest" of resources from prey cities is done in a way that doesn't completely cripple that city. Catch and release, basically.

Any help you all can give me would be vastly appreciated, thank you!

I am drawing inspiration from the Mortal Engines book and movie setting, if this helps explain what I mean by "moving city".

(Edit: I'm relatively new to Stack Exchange, if I've messed up any other rules or norms for the community please let me know and I'll edit to fix)

Comment: For all this information you should look at the illustrated guide to mortal engines. Philip Revee goes into great deals about the workings of the cities Godshawk engines which are omnivorous and can burn wood, oil, coal and gas. I worked out that a city with a population of

Comment: I’m sorry i am also new. I joined yesterday.

Comment: I've never heard of 100 people referred as a small city before.

Comment: I'll look at that, thank you! And how are you calculating the 1.68 million tonnes?

Comment: And yeah, I probably should've called it a "small town", but I wanted to use consistent wording and I'm referring to the other two as moving cities, so, I decided to call it a small city.

Comment: One house requires 50,000 bricks each weighing 2.4 kg x20 if 5 people lived in each house and you have 2.4 million kgs or 240 000 tonnes. The nasa crawler can cary roughly 800 000 kgs  and has roughly 5,000 Hp.

Comment: But it uses electrical motors not steam pistons.

Comment: Please remember that comments are intended for requesting clarification and suggesting improvements. They are not for conversation.

Comment: First question that needs to be answered is:  At this tech + magic level, what proportion of the population needs to be involved in agriculture?  Second question:  Where is the food being grown?  (That is, do cities include crop fields etc or does all/most food need to ultimately be sourced from the "sedentary settlements" at the bottom of the food chain?)

Comment: First of all, @PrinceThomasthe42nd is correct, what can't you find from Philip Reeve's *Mortal Engines* book series and the certain-to-exist trove of encyclopedic data that exists about them? We're flexible with new users, but we do expect people to do their research before asking here - and since you're obviously using Reeve's stuff.... Also, please note that Stack Exchange allows you to ask just one question: you've asked at least five. A summary of the rules is [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8491/40609).

Comment: @KerrAvon2055, sort of both - cities will include some foods grown inside them, victory garden style, but will primarily source their food from "food forest" style harvest of resources in the local areas that they travel to, similar to how historical nomadic groups have sourced food. They also do source a lot from the settlements at the bottom of the food chain.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact, apologies about the rules, I'll edit my post to clarify what my primary question is. 

And regarding Reeve's stuff - I'm using his work for inspiration, but I don't actually have the books, or any convenient way to acquire them, which is why I was hoping I could ask folks here who know things about population numbers and similar regarding how this could realistically work

Comment: If you want to know how it would realistically work, [this video](https://youtu.be/jNu2Jkyh0xg) might help out, at least with the math part.

Comment: One more thing: please watch your use of the word "realistically." "Realistically," what you're trying to do is impossible for hundreds of reasons. And not just impossible, it's uber-cool for a story but down right silly to consider "realistically." The energy requirements alone to move a "city" far outweigh any possible value of having a single-unit mobile city (now, on water....). Please remember you're shooting for suspension of disbelief - nothing more.

Comment: I would say that realistically the population size of a giant, seam powered moving city would be zero.

Comment: Thank you for the help, everyone, I appreciate it! @ProjectApex, that's a really useful video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give some background perspective, let's look at the world's largest floating city - the [Symphony of the Seas.](https://gangwaze.com/blog/royal-caribbean-ships-by-size#1-symphony-of-the-seas-size)

> 1. SYMPHONY OF THE SEAS SIZE The Royal Caribbean Symphony of the Seas
>    has a construction date of 2018 and a total size of 228,081 gross
>    tons. The ship measures 1,188 feet (362 meters) in length and falls in
>    line as number 1 among Royal Caribbean's 36 existing and former cruise
>    ships. It’s included in Royal Caribbean’s Oasis Class. At full
>    capacity, the Symphony of the Seas holds 7,718 passengers. That
>    includes 5,518 cruise vacationers and 2,200 staff members. The Royal
>    Caribbean Symphony of the Seas total number of staterooms is 2,745.
>
> Symphony of the Seas Size & Stats Gross Tonnage: 228,081 GT Ship
> Length: 1,188 feet (362 meters) Beam: 137 feet (42 meters) Draft: 31
> feet (9 meters) Max Speed: 25 mph (22 knots) Year Built: 2018 Years
> Served: 2018-Present Capacity: 5,518 passengers Crew Members: 2,200
> Total on Board: 7,718 Total Staterooms: 2,745 Flagged Country: Ship
> Cost: $1,350 Million Status: active

This ship is so humongous, it would certainly be considered as a self-contained town, with all amenities typical of one. However, the living accommodations leave a lot to be desired, should one be spending their entire life on such a ship. It is so big it could carry the largest American aircraft carrier Gerald R. Ford inside of its confines and still have room for a corvette or two.

So if somehow you can get a ship of this size to operate on land under steam punk, it would seem that around 10.000 people would be an upper limit based on what we currently have on earth. Maybe cut the ship off at the waterline, put a flat bottom on it, and put mega huge wheel boogies under it. Something [along the lines of](https://newatlas.com/the-worlds-biggest-production-tire--the-63-inch-titan/9726/):

> July 31, 2008 Mine operators are increasingly adopting larger
> equipment to lower operating costs and a new class of ultra-large
> machinery is demanding bigger tyres. Earlier this week, Titan Tire
> shipped its first giant 63-inch off-the-road (OTR) tire and wheel
> assemblies. The tires, each measuring nearly 14 feet tall and weighing
> approximately 12,500 pounds, are being shipped to Canada’s oil sands
> for use in mining applications and Titan envisages a worldwide market
> of 900 tires a year.

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you!